# Proving Jordan chain for nilpotent matrix is linearly independent

Tags: independence, jordan-normal-form, nilpotent-groups

I am looking for a proof for the Jordan chain $\{L^ix, L^{i-1}x, \dots, x\}$ being independent, where $L$ is a nilpotent matrix of index $k$, $i<k$ and $x \neq 0$. I have tried the following. Suppose the set is not linearly independent, then $\exists$ at least one $m$, $0\leq m \leq i$, such that:
\begin{align}
L^mx &= \sum_{j=0, j\neq m}^{i} \alpha_jL^jx \hspace{5mm} \text{multiplying by $L^{k-m}$} \\
0 &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} \alpha_jL^{k+m-j}x.
\end{align}
I am stuck here trying to prove a contradiction. Any help would be appreciated.

I am referring to the article [here](http://sites.millersville.edu/rumble/Math.422/jordannil.pdf).

Comment: What does it mean for you that the above set of vectors is a Jordan chain?

Comment: @Exodd Suppose there is a vector space $M_i$ defined by $R(L^{i})\cap N(L)$. Then for any $y\in M_i$, $\exists$ $x\in R(L^i)$ such that $L^ix = y$. Then we extend this to get the Jordan chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the Jordan chain is "complete" for the given vector $x$ such that $L^i x\neq 0$ but $L^{i+1}x=0.$ Now let
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^j x = 0
$$
Then we multiply with $L^i$ from the left:
$$
L^i\sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^j x = \sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^{i+j} x = \alpha_0 L^i x
$$
As $L^ix\neq 0,$ we can conclude that $\alpha_0=0.$
Now
$$
L^{i-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^j x = \sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^{i+j-1} x = \alpha_0 L^{i-1} x + \alpha_1 L^i x = \alpha_1 L^i x
$$
which means that $\alpha_1 =0$ and so on and so forth, such that we get
$$
L^{i-m}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^j x = \sum_{j=0}^{i}\alpha_j L^{i+j-m} x = \alpha_0 L^{i-m} x + \ldots + \alpha_m L^i x = \alpha_m L^i x
$$
for $0\leq m\leq i$ and we can conclude $\alpha_0 = \ldots = \alpha_i = 0.$