# Finding Jordan basis of arbitrary nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with part 2 of the following problem.

Let $D \in L(V, V)$ and let $v \in V$ be such that for some $k \in\{1,2, \ldots\}$, $D^k v \neq 0$ but $D^{k+1} v=0$.

1. Show that $U=\operatorname{Span}\left(v, D(v), D^2(v), \ldots, D^k(v)\right)$ is an invariant subspace for the operator $D$.
2. By the result of Part 1, we may view $D$ as an element of $L(U, U)$. Find a basis for $U$ which puts $D$ into Jordan Canonical Form, and justify your result.

For 1, we want to show that $Du \in U \text{ } \forall u \in U$. Suppose that
$u \in U$. Then there must exist $a_0,...a_k \in \mathbb{F}$ such that
$$u = a_0v + a_1D(v)+ \cdots + a_kD^k(v)$$
applying $D$ to both sides gives
\begin{equation*}
      \begin{split}
        Du &= D(a_0v + a_1D(v)+ \cdots + a_kD^k(v))\\
        &= a_0Dv + a_1D^2(v) + \cdots + a_kD^{k + 1}(v)\\
        &= a_0Dv + a_1D^2(v) + \cdots + a_{k-1}D^k(v)
      \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
Thus $Du \in U$ and $U$ is invariant under $D$.

I'm not sure where to begin with two. I feel like I don't know enough about $D$ (like what it does to basis vectors) to find a Jordan basis. Any guidance is greatly appreicated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like I don't know enough about $D$ (like what it does to basis vectors) to find a Jordan basis.

Perhaps this is a sign that you should find a basis for which you know exactly how $D$ behaves :)

$v, Dv, D^2 v, \ldots, D^k v$ is a spanning set of $U$. If you can show it is also [linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738670/proving-jordan-chain-for-nilpotent-matrix-is-linearly-independent), then it is a basis for $U$.

Now figure out what the matrix of $D$ is with respect to this basis.